# finding elements of array in another array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have this code where i'm trying to find if elements of t arrays occur in  c1 array

expected result should be t1 , t3 , t6

```
import numpy as np

t1=np.array([1,1,0,0])
t2=np.array([0,0,1,1])
t3=np.array([1,0,1,0])
t4=np.array([0,1,0,1])
t5=np.array([1,0,0,1])
t6=np.array([0,1,1,0])
two_matrix=np.array([t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6])
c1=[1,1,1,0]
for item in two_matrix:
    if item is part of c1 : # some code
       print(item)
```

Comment: @Piinthesky yes you are right .edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *probably* what you want, but you need to clarify.

```
import numpy as np

t = {}
t[1] = np.array([1,1,0,0])
t[2] = np.array([0,0,1,1])
t[3] = np.array([1,0,1,0])
t[4] = np.array([0,1,0,1])
t[5] = np.array([1,0,0,1])
t[6] = np.array([0,1,1,0])

c = np.array([1,1,1,0])

for k, v in t.items():
    if all(c[i] == v[i] for i in range(len(v)) if v[i] == 1):
        print(v)

# [1 1 0 0]
# [1 0 1 0]
# [0 1 1 0]
```